# Deleting multiple columns in .csv file in unix

Tags: shell

I have csv file with 80 columns and "^A" delimiter. I want to delete few columns from it, can be `1,2,20,31,45,56,77,78,79,80` or what ever column needed.

For Example: I am taking a CSV file with 15 columns
From:

```
2018^A04 14:14:46^A01^AJHFM^A2^ACard^Aacc^A11^A0^AVZ^Aapp^A2^AGold^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A04 14:14:46^A01^AJHFM^A2^ACard^Aacc^A11^A0^AVZ^Aapp^A2^AGold^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A04 14:14:46^A01^AJHFM^A2^ACard^Aacc^A11^A0^AVZ^Aapp^A2^AGold^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A04 14:14:46^A01^AJHFM^A2^ACard^Aacc^A11^A0^AVZ^Aapp^A2^AGold^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A04 14:14:46^A01^AJHFM^A2^ACard^Aacc^A11^A0^AVZ^Aapp^A2^AGold^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A04 14:14:46^A01^AJHFM^A2^ACard^Aacc^A11^A0^AVZ^Aapp^A2^AGold^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A04 14:14:46^A01^AJHFM^A2^ACard^Aacc^A11^A0^AVZ^Aapp^A2^AGold^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A04 14:14:46^A01^AJHFM^A2^ACard^Aacc^A11^A0^AVZ^Aapp^A2^AGold^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A04 14:14:46^A01^AJHFM^A2^ACard^Aacc^A11^A0^AVZ^Aapp^A2^AGold^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A04 14:14:46^A01^AJHFM^A2^ACard^Aacc^A11^A0^AVZ^Aapp^A2^AGold^ACUST^ABB
```

To:

I deleted columns `2,5,7,9,13`

```
2018^A01^AJHFM^ACard^A11^AVZ^Aapp^A2^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A01^AJHFM^ACard^A11^AVZ^Aapp^A2^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A01^AJHFM^ACard^A11^AVZ^Aapp^A2^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A01^AJHFM^ACard^A11^AVZ^Aapp^A2^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A01^AJHFM^ACard^A11^AVZ^Aapp^A2^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A01^AJHFM^ACard^A11^AVZ^Aapp^A2^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A01^AJHFM^ACard^A11^AVZ^Aapp^A2^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A01^AJHFM^ACard^A11^AVZ^Aapp^A2^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A01^AJHFM^ACard^A11^AVZ^Aapp^A2^ACUST^ABB  
2018^A01^AJHFM^ACard^A11^AVZ^Aapp^A2^ACUST^ABB
```

It worked using awk but it's giving empty spaces in the deleted columns.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="^A"} {$1=$2="";gsub(",+",",",$0)}1' filename
```

Comment: This command is working "cut -f2-4,77-78 -d $'\x01' ". But the only thing I have to select all the columns I need not other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you assign to a field, awk will rewrite the line using the **output** field separator. You need to set that, as by default it is a space. Do this:

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "^A" }
```